# Express Router Regex - How can I match a string literal that includes a hyphen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, routes

I have two routes. When accessing `test` it will also match with `example-test` because of the hyphen. I've tried to escape it `\-` but it still matches. How can I correctly match exact without calling both routes?

**See example**:

```
app.use('/site/(:locale/)?test(.(xml|xml.gz))?', ...)
app.use('/site/(:locale/)?example-test(.(xml|xml.gz))?', ...)
```

Comment: I've already experimented matching exactly `example-test` outside of express routing's regex support. It is something with express routing that keeps matching both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that, maybe

```
/site/(?::locale/)?(?:example-)?test(?:\.xml\.gz|\.xml)
```

might be OK to look into.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3YlVuA/1)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3YlVuA/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/3YlVuA/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: inputting this value to express returns an exception of invalid regular expression given. I'm currently working out the kinks. Will update if I figure it out.
 
I inputted `app.use('/site/(?::locale/)?(?:example-)test(?:\.xml\.gz|\.xml)', ...)`

Exception outputted 

Invalid Regular Expression `/^\/site\/(?:?:(?:([^\/]+?))\/)?test(?:\.xml\.gz|\.xml)?\/?(?=\/|$)/`